# 500 Error on PHP Image Load

Tags: php

This problem appeared out of the sudden after my program was working for 2 years. When I load a page, a thumb.php GET request is made to load 6-7 images. Now most of them are loaded fine with a 200 response from thumb.php, but there is always 1 image that doesnt load right away and seems to be giving 500 internal server error. If I refresh the page it will load all the images without problem. Its very weird since some of the pages are loading all the images right away without any problem. Can this be a problem if the folder that contains the photos has around 35k files? Any suggestions?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I would suggest looking through the logs and finding out what error is being reported.  With what you've shared we don't have very much to go on.

Comment: Any serverupdates like a jump from php 5.2 to php 5.5.*?

Comment: Add more details like the version of PHP, maybe the error message if there is anything else than the 500 ? Maybe also the two queries sent to your server if their is any difference.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, I have set the PHP memory limit to 128MB, PHP version is 5.2.17 and the thumb.php is Smart Image Resizer 1.4.1.